# Recursive methode which sums up odd numbers

Tags: java, recursion

I would like to write a recursive method that expects an integer N as input and then adds and returns all odd numbers from 1 to N inclusive, but how do I give the sum? Is my solution right?

```
   public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sum(10);

    }

    static int sum(int n)
    {
        if(n % 2 == 0) {
            n--;
        }
        if (n <= 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return n + sum(n-2); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run it?

Comment: *Is my solution right?* what is the current output?

Comment: Run the method and tell us the current output together with the expected output. Please read through [ask] and [help], thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but unfortunately it shows me nothing because I do not know how I could spend the result.

Comment: Print it using `System.out.println(...);`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I know that. Only I do not know how to sum up "save" and could spend as a result.

Comment: Also - you might find changing `n <= 1` to `n < 1` but it looks like it should work.

Comment: It sounds like you don't know that. Print what the method returns and tell us what it returns. `System.out.println(sum(10));` or `int result = sum(10); System.out.println(result);`. And don't forget to add the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if your solution is right, you need to run it and print the result.
To print, use `System.out.println(..)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int s = sum(10);
    System.out.println(s);
}

static int sum(int n)
{
    if(n % 2 == 0) {
        n--;
    }
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return n + sum(n-2); 
}
```

execute it and see the result to see if it gives right output.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of a similar logic:

```
private static int sum(int i) {
    i = ((i%2) == 0) ? --i : i;
    return (i < 2) ? i : (i+ sum(--i));
}
```